# How to set up dependencies of an npm package to support tree shaking

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am the maintainer of the [React Query Builder](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder) (RQB) library. One of the features of RQB is that you can replace any internal component with a custom version for specialized behaviors and/or styling.

I'm considering publishing a new npm package that consists of prepackaged custom components for RQB. These would include AntD, Chakra UI, Material UI, and Bootstrap versions of most components (as seen in the [demo](https://react-querybuilder.github.io/react-querybuilder/) - [code here](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/tree/master/demo/components)), a `ValueEditor` that uses [react-datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/), a `FieldSelector` that uses `optgroup`s, and a few others.

For a build setup, I’m probably just going to copy the webpack configuration from the main RQB repo, since it works pretty well and does what I need.

My question is about tree shaking. If I publish a Bootstrap version of the `ValueEditor` component, how do I set up my dependencies so that if a user imports that component as shown below, they don’t get *all* the dependencies from *all* the components (AntD, Chakra, etc.)?

User’s package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "<new-rqb-package-name>": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

User’s QueryComponent.{j|t}sx:

```
import { BootstrapValueEditor } from '<new-rqb-package-name>'
```

My first guess is that the libraries my new package would depend on should be `devDependencies` and `peerDependencies`, but not regular `dependencies` (kind of like `react` and `react-dom`). Seems like that way, it would fall to the user to install any dependencies for their particular component. But wouldn’t that make a message show up when running `npm i` or `yarn` that all the `peerDependencies` the user doesn’t have installed are "unmet"? If so, is that an acceptable consequence?

Planned package.json for `<new-rqb-package-name>`:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.6.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "antd": "^4.10.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.6.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "antd": "^4.10.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "react": ">=16.8.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": ">=16.8.0"
  }
}
```